# Is there a way to map invalid strings to a specified default number in tensorflow?

Tags: string, tensorflow

For instance, let's say I am working with a string tensor `strs = ['12', '52', 'apple', '3']` (can be any dimension in general), and I want to map this to a float32 tensor using built-in tf operations. If I were to simply do `tf.strings.to_number(strs)`, then there would be the following error message

```
StringToNumberOp could not correctly convert string: apple [Op:StringToNumber]
```

because clearly 'apple' cannot be interpreted as a number.

My question is: is there a way to specify some default float value (say -1) for the invalid entry to be converted to (in this case 'apple') with purely (vectorized) tensorflow operations. In this case, the desired output would be `[12, 52, -1, 3]`.

The reason for doing this is because we want to perform all data preprocessing operations in a Keras layer and eliminate as much Python dependencies as possible.

Comment: You need to filter the odd element having not same datatype and then replace with -1 before processing